# Doctrine querybuilder result

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I am developing an application using Symfony2 and Doctrine2. I also use Doctrine's QueryBuilder. I have this query:

```
public function getInterpDesberdinak($MarkId)
    {
          $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
              ->select('DISTINCT c.Gordailua, c')
              ->where('c.MarkIdGordailua = :MarkId')
              ->setParameter('MarkId', $MarkId);
          $Emaitza = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
          return $Emaitza;
    }
```

I would like to how the result would I get in $Emaitza would look. Would it be something like:

$Emaitza[0]['Gordailua'] = the first Gordailua value selected.

and then $Emaitza[0][?????] = The first c type object.

I am kind of confused.Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all you need to specify the From clause:

```
$qb->from('YourBundle\Entity\ParentOfGordailua as pg');
```

You can use the: getArrayResult() to fetch the data as an array, if you want get First object from the Object ArrayCollection(when you're using the getResult() you must:

```
$Gordailua = $Emaitza->first()->getGordailua();
```

Look at the reference and exaples: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Comment: I don't think this is correct solution:
 $Emaitza = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

this is an array, you can't call ->first() on an array.

Comment: besides, if you call `$this->createQueryBuilder` from an EntityRepository the `FROM`clause is taken care of

Answer (score 11):

Can't remember how I came to this post, but I even read it and thought, well .. anyways ..

I think he's asking to get the first result, if so .. the query should first know what the maximum size of result is by doing

```
$qb->setMaxResults(1)
```

and then you can call a method that really defines itself

```
$single_result = $qb->getSingleResult()
```

So in the example given the code will look like

```
$qb->getQuery()->setMaxResults(1)->getSingleResult();
```

And of courses, as stated below, if the query returns `null`, an error will be thrown, so here a version which verifies the content of the query

```
if($query = $db->getQuery())
  return $query->setMaxResults(1)->getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Problem here, is that this query will throw an error if your query returns nothing. Example, you querying "id = 1", if id = 1 not exists you will get the error "No result was found for query although at least one row was expected."